# What are these cables in my walls for?

Tags: cables, socket

Can someone help me identify what these cables are for?

I'm guessing (and hoping) the one in the bedroom is for a cat 5 wall socket -- and that these corresponds to some of the cables exiting in the basement ceiling.

**Bedroom wall**

[image: cables wall bedroom]

**Basement ceiling**

[image: cables ceiling basement]

Comment: Doesn't look like cat5: wrong colours, not twisted. Alarm system?

Comment: You're right. Not cat5 unfortunately.

Comment: Hm. Why the downvote? Is this the wrong place for such questions?

Comment: Spy cameras I reckon LOL.

Answer (score 2):

The cables in the top photo seem to be telephone wires, but certainly not cat5 cables. It looks like two telephone wires were connected together.

Cat5 ethernet cables always have 8 insulated wires, grouped into 4 twisted pairs. The cable is thicker and the insulation quite thin so that you can see bulges formed by the twisted pairs.

In the bottom photo I can't see the cable(s), but the colors are wrong for cat 5 cable.

More information on cat5 cable, including the proper colors, can be found e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable).

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. I realize a little research would have ruled out the cat5 possibility.

Comment: Two telephone wires connected together? That sounds like ISDN.